# How to add event listener to a component and remove it when the user click anywhere else in the window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code:

```
const Component = () => {

 const[divShow, setDivShow] = useState(false);

 const toggleDivShow = () => {
   setDivShow(!divShow)
 }

  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={toggleDivShow}>
      {
         divShow && <div>click the button to show me</div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

now, this is working perfectly and toggle showing the `div` when the user click the button but, this only hide the `div` when the user click the button, How to hide the `div` when the user click anywhere else in the window

I tried to add a click event listener to the `window` that set `divShow` to false but unfortunately this didn't work, as this affected the button too and `divShow` always set to false even when i click the button, this is expected i think because the button is a part of the window

**How can i solve this problem??**

Comment: `useEffect` to add and remove event listeners on document.

Comment: @elclanrs I did that, i added a click listener to the window in a useEffect, but the button didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `divShow` to `useEffect` dependency array, also dont forget to call clean up method in useEffect, as multiple document.addEventListener will cause the browser to hang.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [divShow, setDivShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleDivShow = () => {
    setDivShow(!divShow);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   if(divShow){document.addEventListener("click", toggleDivShow)}

   return () => document.removeEventListener("click", toggleDivShow); //cleaning the side effect after un-mount
  }, [divShow]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleDivShow}>
        {divShow && <div>click the button to show me</div>}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you need to add a condition ate the beginning of the useEffect `if (divShow) {document.addEventListener.......}`, please do this so i can accept the answer

Comment: without it any click on the document would show the div, and this is not right